# Grails - Have Root Resolve to a Page

Tags: grails, redirect, controller, root

I have a Grails application that is hooked up to the ROOT of a Tomcat server. When someone goes to the domain, the application redirects to a default controller, like `/main`. Then the browser shows the url `www.x.com/main`, but I would really like it if I could just show `www.x.com`. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change the URL mapping for "/" to use your controller:

```
"/"(controller: 'main', action: 'index')
```

Comment: Hey Burt - revisiting this issue. Can I do the following? If the user is not logged in, map "/" to the login page. If the user is logged in, map "/" to a different page. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible, and quite simple too.

In your UrlMappings.groovy, add the following:

```
"/"(controller: "main")
```

This will resolve to `www.x.com/` but still execute the default action of your `main` controller.

Comment: I'm getting a `302` when I hit my main site. I think it might be because of the authentication on the page, but then it redirects to `/main` anyway, so this isn't working for me.

Comment: It looks like it `302`s about 8 times and gets the jsessionid in the URL. Have you seen this before? Thanks.